# Оптимизированный запрос к mysql

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, select

Нужно спроектировать таблицы и составить к нему запрос таким образом, чтобы запрос был оптимизирован для высоконагруженной база данных.

Имеются сущности заявка и партнер. И заявка и партнер имеют список соответствующих специализаций. Нужно чтобы партнер видел только те заявки, у которых специализации полностью содержатся в списке специализации партнера. Например, заявки со специализациями (проектирование, сопровождение, обучение) будет видна для партнера со списком специализации (проектирование, сопровождение, обучение, администрирование); и для того же партнера НЕ будет видна заявка (проектирование, ПРЕЗЕНТАЦИЯ, обучение)

Запрос должен использовать индексы и не должен содержать filesort и temporary.

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали и с чем столкнулись?

Comment: Изначально сущности хранились в битриксовых инфоблоках. Т.е. значения сущности заявки хранятся в двух таблицах -  таб. 1 основные поля (название, дата изменения и т.д.) и таб. 2 значения множественного поля "специализация". Запрос сводился к подзапросу , группировкам и появлялось условие в having

Comment: @zkhodjaev А что вы называете "составить запрос", для работы с системой потребуются десятки разных запросов и каждый в отдельности надо будет рассматривать с точки зрения оптимизации. И вы думаете, что вашей информации достаточно для действительно правильной структуры базы ? Надо каждый атрибут рассматривать как, кто и зачем с ним работает и т.п.

Comment: Да хоть как. Какая вам нужна еще информация?

Comment: @Mike -------------------------

Comment: Погуглите рекурсионный запрос, а лучше сделайте схему БД и добавьте скрин, это не так уж сложно

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich А чем бы тут помог рекурсивный и в mysql кстати рекурсивных запросов нет

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/43955/ Вот тут почитайте

Comment: Примерная схема БД. ![Схема](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9gmy/gpS1teb27). Проект на битрикс. Значения специализации хранятся в отдельной таблице (просто числа). Соответственно значения специализации заявки и партнера совпадают. Таблицы partners и partners_specs в запросе не учавствуют.

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich В приведенной вами статье как раз говорится, что на mysql рекурсивные запросы невозможны, только внешними средствами типа php (хотя на самом деле можно еще хранимыми процедурами). Но я тут не вижу никаких рекурсивно зависящих данных

Comment: @zkhodjaev И вашу задачу без group by выполнить нереально. Вернее можно битовое поле сделать, но это применимо только если  специализаций заведомо меньше 64 и у них соотв. id не превышают 64. Причем это не в заказе или партнера, а всего существующих. А вообще вам надо сделать боле менее нормальную схему, сделать запрос, когда он будет тормозить задать вопрос с указанием структуры, запроса и `explain` (т.е. плана выполнения) этого запроса и тогда уже можно будет подумать об оптимизации конкретного запроса

Comment: @Mike пришел к тожу же выводу, что без group by и having сделать нереально

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.
У вас отчетливо прослеживаются 5 сущностей.
1) заявка
2) партнёр
3) специализация
4) специализация у заявки
5) специализация у партнёра

Есть две связи многие-ко-многим через сущности 4)5), реализуемые внешними ключами:
1) заявка - специализация у заявки - специализация
2) партнёр - специализация у партнёра - специализация

Вот. Обратите внимание на кластерные индексы ключей вспомогательных таблиц.
Порядок столбцом выбран именно таким образом, чтобы ниже приведённый запрос выполнялся быстрее всего.
Если нужен будет обратный поиск(найти партнёров по заявке), возможно следует сделать и обратный индекс.

```
USE tempdb;
--Clear
IF OBJECT_ID('Query_Specialisations') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Query_Specialisations
IF OBJECT_ID('Partner_Specialisations') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Partner_Specialisations
IF OBJECT_ID('Queries') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Queries
IF OBJECT_ID('Partners') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Partners
IF OBJECT_ID('Specialisations') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Specialisations

CREATE TABLE Queries(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  name NVARCHAR(255)
  CONSTRAINT PK_Queries PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    Id ASC
  )
)

CREATE TABLE Partners(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  name NVARCHAR(255)
  CONSTRAINT PK_Partners PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    Id ASC
  )
)

CREATE TABLE Specialisations(
  Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  name NVARCHAR(255)
  CONSTRAINT PK_Specialisations PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    Id ASC
  )
)

CREATE TABLE Query_Specialisations(
  Query_id INT,
  Specialisation_id INT
  CONSTRAINT PK_Query_Specialisations PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    --обратите внимание на порядок столбцов. для хорошего решения текущий задачи нужен именно такой порядок
    --сначала по специализации, потом по заявке
    Specialisation_id ASC,
    Query_id ASC
  )
)

GO

ALTER TABLE Query_Specialisations  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Query_Specialisations_Queries FOREIGN KEY(Query_id)
REFERENCES Queries (Id)

ALTER TABLE Query_Specialisations  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Query_Specialisations_Specialisations FOREIGN KEY(Specialisation_id)
REFERENCES Specialisations (Id)

GO

CREATE TABLE Partner_Specialisations(
  Partner_id INT,
  Specialisation_id INT
  CONSTRAINT PK_Partner_Specialisations PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
    --обратите внимание на порядок столбцов. для хорошего решения текущий задачи нужен именно такой порядок
    --сначало по партнёру, потом по специализации
    Partner_id ASC,
    Specialisation_id ASC
  )
)

GO

ALTER TABLE Partner_Specialisations  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Partner_Specialisations_Partners FOREIGN KEY(Partner_id)
REFERENCES Partners (Id)

ALTER TABLE Partner_Specialisations  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT FK_Partner_Specialisations_Specialisations FOREIGN KEY(Specialisation_id)
REFERENCES Specialisations (Id)

SELECT PS.Partner_id, QS.Query_id
FROM(
  SELECT *, COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY PS.Partner_id)Cnt --запомним количество специализаций для каждого партнёра
  FROM Partner_Specialisations PS
  WHERE PS.Partner_id = 5 -- тут можно задать интервал вместо конкретного партнёра
)PS
   JOIN Query_Specialisations QS ON PS.Specialisation_id = QS.Specialisation_id
GROUP BY PS.Partner_id, QS.Query_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(Cnt) --смотрим, что количество совпавших специализаций равно количеству специализаций партнера
```

**UPD:** Вопрос по MySql, сразу не заметил.
Приведённый код работает под MS SQL.
Но смысл остается тот же. Делаем 5 сущностей, нужные внешние ключи и радуемся жизни:)

Comment: У меня нет возможности проверить это на MS SQL.

Comment: Но по коду выше я понял, что запрос получит все заявки, у которые список специализации равны списку специализациям партнерам. А мне нужно, чтобы заявки специализации СОДЕРЖАЛИСЬ в списке партнеров.  К тому же, на mysql group by и having приводило к дополнительному обходу таблицы, что критично для таблиц с большим количеством данных

Comment: Нет. Запрос находит именно СОДЕРЖАНИЕ одного множества в другом.

Comment: @zkhodjaev В списке партнеров заявки содержаться не могут, это противоречит принципам построения реляционных баз данных. Они в любом случае будут в отдельных таблицах. И один запрос вам ничего не решит. Надо рассматривать всю систему. И group by может работать даже на mysql совершенно по разному, все зависит от того какие индексы построены, какова селективность запроса в части where и еще куче всяких мелочей. Одно и то же условие написанное чуть по разному может приводить к кардинально разным планам выполнения. Оптимизировать любой запрос можно только на ваших реальных данных.

Comment: На MySql на той же схеме данных запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:
**upd:** вынес в отдельный ответ, так как тут запрос не форматируется.

Comment: @pegoopik спасибо за ответ! но мне пока это не помогает

Answer (score 0):

На MySql на той же схеме данных(из предыдущего ответа) запрос будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
SELECT PS.Partner_id, QS.Query_id
FROM Partner_Specialisations PS
  JOIN Query_Specialisations QS ON PS.Specialisation_id = QS.Specialisation_id
WHERE PS.Partner_id = 5 -- тут можно задать интервал вместо конкретного партнёра
GROUP BY PS.Partner_id, QS.Query_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECt COUNT(*)
  FROM Query_Specialisations QS2
  WHERE QS.Query_id = QS2.Query_id 
)--количество совпадающий специализаций = количеству специализаций у заявки
```

И без группировки вам тут не обойтись

Comment: Согласен, без группировок тут не обойтись.  Тогда мне критично изменить запрос таким образом, чтобы не создавались временные таблицы. Возможно этот запрос изменить таким образом? В приципе, для бизнесс-процесса подойдет ограничение количества заявок до 500. Просто по тому алгоритму, которые вы предложили, я не вижу это.

Comment: Где вы у меня в запросе увидели временные таблицы? Query_Specialisations и Partner_Specialisations самые что ни на есть обыкновенные таблицы.